# SignalR integration with ABP Angular version

Tags: typescript, signalr, aspnetboilerplate, .net-core-3.1, asp.net-boilerplate

I'm trying to use SignalR library with ABP Application (.NET Core 3.1 with Angular version) but when I came to the last step that is mentioned in the official documentation, I didn't know where I should put the code:

```
var chatHub = null;

abp.signalr.startConnection(abp.appPath + 'signalr-myChatHub', function (connection) {
    chatHub = connection; // Save a reference to the hub

    connection.on('getMessage', function (message) { // Register for incoming messages
        console.log('received message: ' + message);
    });
}).then(function (connection) {
    abp.log.debug('Connected to myChatHub server!');
    abp.event.trigger('myChatHub.connected');
});

abp.event.on('myChatHub.connected', function() { // Register for connect event
    chatHub.invoke('sendMessage', "Hi everybody, I'm connected to the chat!"); // Send a message to the server
});
```

**I don't know, where should I put the above code?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in `ngOnInit` of `AppComponent` in [app.component.ts](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/175f8be981a069add870625e96f8a376abcc6a54/angular/src/app/app.component.ts#L23):

```js
export class AppComponent extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit {
    ...

    ngOnInit(): void {
        ...

        // SignalRAspNetCoreHelper.initSignalR(); // Replace this line with the block below
        SignalRAspNetCoreHelper.initSignalR(() => {
            var chatHub = null;

            abp.signalr.startConnection(abp.appPath + 'signalr-myChatHub', function (connection) {
                chatHub = connection; // Save a reference to the hub

                connection.on('getMessage', function (message) { // Register for incoming messages
                    console.log('received message: ' + message);
                });
            }).then(function (connection) {
                abp.log.debug('Connected to myChatHub server!');
                abp.event.trigger('myChatHub.connected');
            });

            abp.event.on('myChatHub.connected', function() { // Register for connect event
                chatHub.invoke('sendMessage', "Hi everybody, I'm connected to the chat!"); // Send a message to the server
            });
        });

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this exception appeared  ====>  Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to invoke 'register' due to an error on the server. HubException: Method does not exist. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to that error?   I'm running into the same issue.  Thanks in advance.